# About select option value

Tags: php, javascript

Hmm...this question may sounds silly , hope you all don't mind...

If I have a drop list:

```
 <select name="myoption" onchange="document.textbox.value=this.value">
 <option value="1">A</option>
 <option value="2">B</option>
 <option value="3">C</option>
 </select>

 <input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox">
```

So with this now the textbox will display what is selected , but is it possible to display the A,B,C instead of 1,2,3?

Actually I need a drop-list which will display 2 different values to 2 textbox,such as if A is selected,textbox1 will display "A" and textbox2 will display "1".

I don't know if it is possible and I tried for some times already...can someone give me some hints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried onchange="document.textbox.value=this.text; document.textbox2.value=this.value"?

Comment: @hafichuk Thanks for your reply,I tried it and it show me "undefined" error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I would just externalize all javascript into a separate file to avoid mixing markup and scripts.

So the script:

```
// subscribe for the DOM ready event to ensure that you 
// are manipulating the DOM only when it is loaded
window.onload = function() {
    // subscribe for the onchange event of the dropdown
    document.getElementById('myoption').onchange = function() {
        // fetch the text of the currently selected element
        var text = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

        // and assign it to the corresponding input
        document.getElementById('textbox').value = text;
    };
};
```

and the markup:

```
<select name="myoption" id="myoption">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox" />
```

and a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5PTvc/2/).

Comment: Really thanks for your example and demo , you help me a lot Darin.Thanks again,really thanks.